# Global union for different modules

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, avr

I have MCU code (for AVR) with set of different drivers. Driver in use is selected at startup time (in init code) and only one of the drivers will be used at a time. Therefore, i can alias all of RAM segments into the same location. That is required, as RAM is very limited and all of drivers require 2-3 KB of storage for buffers etc.

Currently i have structures `typedef`'ed in all header files:

#### driver1.h:

```
typedef struct {
    // Driver-specific variables for internal use.
    // None of those and accessed from outside C-file
    int internal_variable1_for_driver1;
    int internal_variable2_for_driver1;
    ...
} st_driver1_t;
```

Other drivers have similar structures

#### In all_drivers.h:

```
#include "driver1.h"
#include "driver2.h"
#include "driver3.h"
...
union {
    st_driver1_t DRV1;
    st_driver2_t DRV2;
    st_driver3_t DRV3;
    ...
} DRV;
```

DISCLAIMER: I understand that all RAM access from modules, other than selected one, should be disabled as it will alter whole union. I have a lot of ASM code in portfolio and that's obvious for me.

Now i have some conflicts because i have to include all_drivers.h, and therefore all driverN.h files into each driver. I want to hide all those headers from all of other drivers.

Is it ok to define all driver-specific structures with `__attribute__((common))` in C-files and therefore hide all of structure from headers. As i understand, linker will merge all those structures into overlapping segment and create some analog of union.

#### driver1.c:

```
struct __attribute__((common)) {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    ...
} DRV;
```

#### driver2.c:

```
struct __attribute__((common)) {
    long OtherVar1;
    int ExtraOne;
    ...
} DRV;
```

Also, should I define those structs as `static` or not? Will this solution be stable or is it undocumented hack?

Comment: You should use neither of this - including the weird union which looks like the wrong solution for implementing either a compiler switch or polymorphism. Forget about non-standard GNU stuff too. `static` is usually good enough as poor man's private encapsulation for simple drivers. In case you need something more intricate like multiple instances of the same driver then check out opaque types: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Comment: "all of drivers require 2-3 KB of storage for buffers etc" This sounds like very strange design. Are they LCD drivers or why do you need that much RAM for?

Comment: @Lundin i have a universal device that should work with lots of slave devices, while all of them use incompatible protocols. RAM is used mainly for Rx/Tx buffers (about 1KB each). Working mode selected using runtime switch (from EEPROM)

Comment: What kind of bus requires buffers that large? Ethernet with full-blown TCP/IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to define all driver-specific structures with `__attribute__((common))`

With GCC and compatible compilers, you can use `__attribute__((__common__))` for common variables (and `__attribute__((__no_common__))` if some variables should not be common, but common is the default).

GCC switched its default behaviour from `-fcommon` to `-fno-common` some time ago (in 2020 with [v10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html)), so you can also compile all compilation units that need this with `-fcommon`.

> should I define those structs as `static` [...]?

No. There are some conditions that objects must meet to be coalesced as common:

- The objects are global (thus also in static storage).
- The objects don't have initializers.
- The objects have the same (assembly) name.
- The compiler must be advised to put the objects in common as discussed above.

Sometimes it's preferred that the objects don't have the same name on C/C++ level, for example that the object for driver1 is named `driver1` etc.  That's fine if the objects have the same name on assembly level, which can be achieved by using the same assembly name for all such objects.  This is a feature provided by GCC.  The following example sets the assembly name to `asm_name`, so in the assembly code the name `asm_name` will be used, but in C code you use `driver1`:

```cpp
typedef struct { ... } driver1_t;

__attribute__((__common__))
driver1_t driver1 __asm ("asm_name");
```

If the ABI requires leading underscores, you should use a name that fits that ABI and use an assembly name that starts with an `_` like `_asm_name`.

There are use cases where common is much clearer and more convenient than putting all objects into a union, so don't be discouraged by these comments.